# Having session error when redirecting to another page after sign_up

Tags: php, session

I am trying to set value in a session variable "$_SESSION['user_id']", and it is working fine on my server side, but when I uploaded it on client's server, then it shows empty value in that variable. Here is the code:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
    $select="select email from credentials where email='".$_POST['email']."'";
    $select_run=mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
    $select_num=mysql_num_rows($select_run);
    if($select_num > 0):
        $nok="Email Address already exists. Please choose another.";
    else:
        $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['dob']));
        $name = $_POST['fname']." ".$_POST['lname'];
        $query="insert into credentials(fullname,email,pass) values('$name','".$_POST['email']."',
        '".md5($_POST['pass'])."')";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = mysql_insert_id();
        $send_mail=$db->send_mail3($_POST['email'],$name);
        $ok="You are successfully registered";
        forceRedirectAdmin("booking_code.php");
    endif; 
endif;
```

The problem is $_SESSION['user_id'] shows empty value when the user redirect to booking_code.php.

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` before any output in your code? Note that you also need this in your booking_code.php as well.

Comment: Check this page code booking_code.php

Comment: i have already started the session, it is working fine on my server, but it shows empty value on client's server.

Comment: use `phpinfo()` and check the `session.* settings`. on client server

Comment: In both pages you don't get the session value, right?

Comment: yes..., the problem is, value is not storing in session variable, it vanish within less than a second. but why?

Comment: what's the permissions/ownership on `/var/lib/php/session` on client server?